# Pandas: Modify list elements of a column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to modify element of list in a column with another column value.

**df is as:**

```
Letter      Action
'2G'       ['a','b']
'2G'       ['a','c','d']
'3G'       ['a']
'5G'       ['a','b','c','d','e']
'4G'       ['d']
```

I expect

```
Action
['2Ga','2Gb']
['2Ga','2Gc','2Gd']
['3Ga']
['5Ga','5Gb','5Gc','5Gd','5Ge']
['5Gd']
```

---

my own attempt which is slow and returns a map object.

```
df['new'] = df.Action.apply(lambda x : map(lambda z: df['Letter']+z ,x))
```

Comment: Show us your attempt please so that we can work on that.

Comment: ```df['new'] = df.Action.apply(lambda x : map(lambda z: df['Letter']+z ,x))``` I tried this, but it takes long and returns Map object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `explode` and `.agg(list)` after applying a `sum` row wise.

if you happen to have `string` object of a list you can apply `pd.eval` to the column

`df['Action'].map(pd.eval)`

```
df1 = df.explode('Action').sum(axis=1).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

---

```
df1 = df.explode('Action')[['Letter','Action']]\
        .sum(axis=1).groupby(level=0).agg(list)


0                   [2Ga, 2Gb]
1              [2Ga, 2Gc, 2Gd]
2                        [3Ga]
3    [5Ga, 5Gb, 5Gc, 5Gd, 5Ge]
4                        [4Gd]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes thanks, can you please help on this too, my df has many columns i just need to sum column "Letter"

Comment: @MahdiAbadinia see edit

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

def join_columns(s):
    letter = s.loc['Letter']
    action = s.loc['Action']
    joined_columns = [letter + value for value in action]

    return joined_columns


df['new_Action'] = df.apply(join_columns, axis=1)
```

The output:

```
|   | Letter | Action          | new_Action                 |
|---|--------|-----------------|----------------------------|
| 0 | 2G     | [a, b]          | [2Ga, 2Gb]                 |
| 1 | 2G     | [a, c, d]       | [2Ga, 2Gc, 2Gd]            |
| 2 | 3G     | [a]             | [3Ga]                      |
| 3 | 5G     | [a, b, c, d, e] | [5Ga, 5Gb, 5Gc, 5Gd, 5Ge]  |
| 4 | 4G     | [d]             | [4Gd]                      |
```

Comment: This one works too but Umar.H 's answer is faster.